# Repeating two variables

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I have one of each ID (e.g. only one `X` and one `Y`) but I want each ID to repeat ten times with the corresponding number next to it.

I have very limited experience with VBA but this is a problem that seems to be solvable by VBA only.

What would the VBA code be?

Comment: I'm afraid your question is very hard to understand. Can you show your desired input and output?

Comment: _"but this is a problem that seems to be solvable by VBA only"_ I highly doubt that

Comment: try using auto fill?

Comment: I would suggest to close this question: it's too broad and sounds more like a request for code-writing service/online tutoring. Thanks for the understanding. Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you just want to copy each row in the file 10 times.

Try this:

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim i As Integer
Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim row As Integer

With ActiveSheet
lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
End With

Range("A1").Activate

For row = 1 To lastRow
    For i = 1 To 9
        Rows(ActiveCell.row).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
    Next i
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
Next row

End Sub
```